# Navigating backwards using (Ctrl + Tab) key combination

Tags: c#, tabs, navigation, key, reverse

I am (still) in the process of implementing key navigation for an app. I have managed to do just about everything I have set out to do I only have one more tricky issue.

Tab navigation works (cycles through the items I have marked as `TabStop`). What I want now is to have a functionality that cycles backwards through those elements when I press (Ctrl + Tab). While I know how to catch the event and so forth I don't know if there is a direct way of telling him (the code) to `doBackwardsTab()` for example; or do I have to implement it by hand? (Get the parent of the currently focused element and then focus the previous child).

**P.S: I would love it if there were a `doBackwardsTab()` thingy ;)**

Comment: Shouldn't the key for this be `Ctrl+Shift+Tab`?

Comment: Good point, I've just tried it out and it seems it's just `Shift+Tab`. Now I would like to port that to `Ctrl+Tab`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key press is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and if plain <kbd>Tab</kbd> works then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will too.

This is the keypress that all apps use to cycle the focus backwards through your controls.  You request in a comment that you want it to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead. This will destroy the usability of your app. Don't do it. Especially not when the option of doing no coding gives you the right solution!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my call :) I will have to check with a few people and get back to you :)

Comment: @rotSin I'm sure the people in charge will realise the sense of this when you explain that it's already been invented. You can always argue that it's not possible to change it since it's built in to WinForms!!